# split a mercurial repo into different baby repos

Tags: version-control, mercurial

The situation is, I once placed some conceptually related codes into one package in hope of interweaving them gradually later, but it turns out they eventually become independent of each other (can be safely separated). Therefore, I decide it's time to split them into different packages, but I'm not sure how to do it in a way so that I could also keep the respective version control history for each sub-package. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) extension included with the standard distribution is used for this purpose.  Specifically, check out the `--filemap` option, which can include, exclude and rename files and directories when converting from one database to another.

Comment: Great! Just finished the conversion